# ASP.net 5 RC1 - Can't Reference System.Web.Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using only the Core CLR, which could be the reason that I can't reference it.

I've got the following in my project.json:

```
...
"frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        ...
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
      }
    }
  },
...
```

I referenced Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, which I believe should let me reference System.Web.Mvc from my code. But no.

My Controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc; // "Red underline under "Web"
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Authorize] // Red underlined
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        // Code inside not shown because it's not the issue.
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the [Authorize] attribute in one of my Web API controllers.

---

**UPDATE**. I should also need to reference the new package Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization.

After about half an hour, hovering over the red-underlined [Authorize] attribute, the Intellisense gave me the suggestion to reference Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization. It didn't give me that option until just now.

Also, I've googled for the Authorize attribute for ASP.net 5, and all results and tutorials tell me to reference System.Web.Mvc. Turns out that all those tutorials are older.

Comment: Please don't edit the solution in your Question. Post an answer and mark it as checked, as soon as the grace period expired, otherwise the Question will be forever marked as open and stackoverflow will pick it up and show in the unanswered question section. This is how Stack overflow works

Comment: Thank you. I always thought that only other users can mark my responses as answered.

Comment: You can too, but there is a grace period of 2 days (48 hours). Check the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Mickael I have some input for you for a question you recently posted on another stackexchange site... for some reason I can't comment there, and I don't want to make it a full answer. Would you consider emailing me at "rofi cut me", reversed, spaces removed, at the email platform hosted by the search-engine company headquartered in Mountain View?

Answer (score 1):

Based on lucky discovery, I needed Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization to use [Authorize]. No tutorial or even googling for this gave me this info.

project.json: Note, new reference Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization;

```
...
"frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
        ...
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
      }
    }
  },
...
```

Controller:

```
// using System.Web.Mvc; // Removed this line - old. Possibly changed as far back as Beta8
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization; // Added this line. It's new.
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Authorize] // No longer red-underlined. This is from Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        // Code inside not shown because it's not the issue.
    }
}
```